# Create a formula in Excel, help needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to program a formula to get one number in Excel and I don't know how.

If I have the next table:

```
    A   B   C
1   1   100
2   2   81
3   3   75
4   4   60
5   5   40
6   6   30
7   7   10
8   8   5
9   9   2
10  10  1
11
12
13
14
15  25
```

I want to put a number in a cell, for example the number 25 at cell A15. The formula should check the table at colum B, check which is the first number that is below that number (25 in this case) and return the number that is in the row A.

For example:

- If the input is 25, the output of the formula should be 7.
- If the input is 50, the output of the formula should be 5.
- If the input is 6, the output of the formula should be 8.

Could you help with the formula that is needed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(A15,B1:B10,-1))+1
```

Comment: Just beat me to it with the same answer while I was deciding whether to answer or ask the OP what they've already tried.

Comment: Placing the +1 outside the end will return 11 if the given number is 0.  Placing the +1 inside the last bracket will return #REF if given 0. Depends what the OP wants with numbers outside the range.

Comment: Thanks, I am checking what best fits me. I am checking as well, "-1", "0" and "1" at the MATCH.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help. I was trying to make it without the INDEX, and I didn't know how to make it. Thanks!!

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - If **1** (the default) is used for the third *match_type* parameter then the *lookup_array* **must** be in ascending order. If **-1** is used for the third *match_type* parameter then the *lookup_array* **must** be in descending order. You **cannot** change a 1 to a -1 without flipping the sort order of the lookup_array if you expect to return dependable results. With a **0** (exact match) the order does not matter.

Comment: @Jeeped.  I think you misunderstood me.  Yes, the `MATCH(A15,B1:B10,-1)` must be descending as you stated.  I was talking about the final +1.  `=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(A15,B1:B10,-1))+1` will return 11 if A15 contains 0 (the formula references the 10 in A10 and adds 1 to it - change A10 value to 12 and the formula returns 13).  `=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(A15,B1:B10,-1)+1)` on the other hand finds the match on A15 and returns that it's the 10th item in the list.  Add 1 to this so it's saying its found the 11th item in the 10 item list - it falls outside the INDEX range and returns the error.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - *mea culpa*, yes... I misread your comment. My bad. Apologies offered. If it is alright, I'll leave the comment for the general reference of others who discover this thread and may not recognize the descending order of the sample data.